# Como criar usuário com senha criptografa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, md5

Como eu faço em minha aplicação ASP.Net MVC 5 e EF 6 para salvar senhas criptografadas no formato MD5 ao criar os usuários?

Comment: Você quer uma função que cria o MD5?

Comment: Usuários por Membership.. ou de uma esquema próprio (tabelas suas criadas no Banco de dados..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método abaixo codifica a senha do usuário em no padrão Base 64, mas pode ser usado MD5 sem problemas, apenas substituindo o método de Base 64 por um MD5 equivalente:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encode password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">Password.</param>
    /// <returns>Encoded password.</returns>
    private string EncodePassword(string password)
    {
        string encodedPassword = password;

        switch (PasswordFormat)
        {
            case MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear:
                break;
            case MembershipPasswordFormat.Encrypted:
                byte[] encryptedPass = EncryptPassword(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
                encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedPass);
                break;
            case MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed:
                HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
                hash.Key = HexToByte(machineKey.ValidationKey);
                encodedPassword =
                  Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ProviderException("Unsupported password format.");
        }

        return encodedPassword;
    }
```

Um método que pode ser implementado nativo está disponível [neste link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160129060456/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx):

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // Calcular o Hash
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
 
    // Converter byte array para string hexadecimal
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Uso:

```
seuModel.Senha = EncodePassword(senha);
```

O problema é que o MD5 não é reversível, ao contrário do Base 64.

Comment: O fato do MD5 não ser reversível não é um problema, é exatamente o que um sistema como esse precisa. Salvo casos muito específicos, um sistema não deve armazenar a senha criptografada de nenhum usuário de forma que ela (a senha) possa ser recriada (via "descriptografia") - se houver um vasamento da informação de hash das senhas elas não podem (facilmente) serem recriadas.

Comment: Eu salientei isso porque usando um provider como o `Membership` há esta possibilidade da reversão da senha. Mas não sei se isso interessa para a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais fácil é adicionar uma biblioteca pelo Nuget (Manage NuGet packages...). [Há inúmeras bibliotecas para isso.](http://www.macoratti.net/11/01/net_ngt.htm)
É melhor assim, porque o algoritmo deve ser muito mais testado, e pela facilidade de se trocar depois para um criptografia melhor (como Blowfish).

A minha sugestão é usar o [CryptSharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/). Se quiser, você pode colocar métodos relacionados à criptografia numa classe a parte:

```
using System;
using CryptSharp;

public static class Criptografia
{
    public static string Codifica(string senha) {
        return Crypter.MD5.Crypt(senha);
    }

    public static bool Compara(string senha, string hash) {
        return Crypter.CheckPassword(senha, hash);
    }
}
```

para depois usar:

```
public ActionResult CriaUsuario(CriaUsuarioViewModel vm) {
    // ...
    var senhaCriptografada = Criptografia.Codifica(senha);
    // ...
}

public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm) {
    // ...

    var usuario = dc.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == vm.Login);

    if (Criptografia.Compara(vm.senha, usuario.Senha)){
        // OK
    }
    else {
        // Senha incorreta
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: André, Tentei usar o cryptsharp para gerar uma senha MD5 hexadecimal de 32 caracteres porem gerou uma de 34 caracteres(sem ser hexadecimal, com pontos, barras, cifroes etc). Voce sabe se tem algum parametro pra eu conseguir fazer a senha como quero?

Comment: Apenas um comentário, levando em conta que alguns usuários (como eu) podem vir a pensar em usar o Blowfish após ler esta resposta: Ele não é mais recomendado, por usar chave de apenas 64 bits. Uma breve googlada dá pra pesquisar boas alternativas para o algoritmo a ser usado.