# Como fazer função para criptografar senha em C#?

Tags: c#, criptografia

Como fazer função para criptografar senha em C#?
Quero pegar o atributo senha e criptografa-lo.

```
    public String gravarCadastro(Cadastro cadastro)
    {
        string sql;
        int retorno;
        string resp;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conexao = Conecta.getConexao(); //abre a conexão com o banco de dados

            sql = "INSERT INTO login ( cpf, nome, login, senha) ";
            sql += "VALUES (@cpf, @nome, @login, @senha)";
            SqlCommand cmd = conexao.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", cadastro.Cpf);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cadastro.Nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", cadastro.Login);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", cadastro.Senha);

            retorno = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (retorno > 0)
            {
                resp = "Cadastro efetuado";
            }
            else
            {
                resp = "Cadastro não realizado";
            }

            //encerra a conexão com o banco de dados
            cmd.Dispose();
            conexao.Dispose();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            //caso a exceção seja a tentativa de inserir um CPF já cadastrado
            resp = "Erro " + ex.ToString();
            /*if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                resp = "CPF já cadastrado";
            }*/
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer, ? já pesquisou algum tipo de criptografia que queira usar?

Comment: Raphael, ajudaria bastante se você pudesse [edit] sua pergunta e acrescentar um pouco mais de detalhes, para entendermos melhor o contexto. Talvez fique um pouco extenso falar de tudo sobre as maneiras de criptografar uma senha, sem saber como vai ser usada.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Poderia postar o código que está utilizando e explicar um pouco mais o que deseja. Aproveitando, o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar usuário com senha criptografa?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15981/como-criar-usu%c3%a1rio-com-senha-criptografa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem varias formas de criptografa dados por ai ( [aqui por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43606/qual-criptografia-usada-pelo-asp-net-identity/43607#43607) ) e uma delas é o [MD5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) ([não é seguro ficar como exemplo](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)), que é uma função de dispersão criptográfica (ou função hash criptográfica) de 128 bits unidirecional (Não tem volta).

A classe abaixo tem tudo que precisar para criar o MD5 (**RetornarMD5**) e compara-lá (**ComparaMD5**) com um MD5 já salvo em seu banco de dados.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace CriarMD5_
{
    public class CriarMD5
    {
        public string RetornarMD5(string Senha)
        {
            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                return RetonarHash(md5Hash, Senha);
            }
        }

        public bool ComparaMD5(string senhabanco, string Senha_MD5)
        {
            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                var senha = RetornarMD5(senhabanco);
                if (VerificarHash(md5Hash, Senha_MD5, senha))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        private string RetonarHash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private bool VerificarHash(MD5 md5Hash, string input, string hash)
        {
            StringComparer compara = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

            if (0 == compara.Compare(input, hash))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Recomendo a leitura desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura).