# Como implementar criptografia na senha?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quero implementar a criptografia da senha no cadastro de usuário.
Achei aqui no stackoverflow este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15981/como-criar-usu%C3%A1rio-com-senha-criptografa) ensinando como usar a criptografia, mas estou em dúvida onde devo adicionar o código.

Esse método deve ser usado na classe ou no controller?

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // Calcular o Hash
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // Converter byte array para string hexadecimal
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Para usar, onde devo chamar?

```
seuModel.Senha = EncodePassword(senha);
```

Controller Pessoas, onde cadastro o usuário:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha")] Pessoas pessoas)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Pessoas.Add(pessoas);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(pessoas);
}
```

Na view cadastro de usuário tenho o campo de senha, desse modo:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: Não misture as responsabilidades. A senha já deve ir `ciptografada` para o seu `model` realizar apenas a gravação no banco, ou seja, esse método seria chamado no seu `controller`.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria utilizar o Identity para seu sistema de login, ele implementa varias ferramentas de segurança, se tiver no inicio de seu projeto vale muito a pena utilizar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Utilize esse método antes de realizar a persistência desse modelo no banco.

Por exemplo:

```
public void SalvarUsuario(Usuario model){
    using (var db = new objetoConexaoBanco()){
        model.Senha = CalculateMD5Hash(model.Senha);
        db.Usuario.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Esse exemplo é utilizando Entity Framework.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha")] Pessoas pessoas)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        pessoas.Senha = CalculateMD5Hash(pessoas.Senha);
        db.Pessoas.Add(pessoas);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(pessoas);
}
```

O exemplo acima é como estaria o seu código.

Comment: Tentei usar esse método dentro do if (ModelState.IsValid) do [HttpPost] do Create, mas ele dava erro no model do CalculateMD5Hash(model)

Comment: Se você estiver realmente usando a mesma função, então não poderia passar model e sim a senha do model, por exemplo `model.Senha = CalculateMD5Hash(model.Senha)`

Comment: Por favor, de uma olhada novamente na resposta pois realizei uma alteração nela.

Comment: Está dando erro "Exception User-Unhandled" no "db.SaveChanges();"

Comment: Para verificar esse erro você deve ver a exception que está sendo retornada, as vezes pode ser o tamanho que está tentando ser populado o campo, posso estar enganado, mas o tamanho do hash MD5 é de 32 caracteres, então você deve dar uma olhada no tamanho da coluna Senha no banco, caso contrário você deve olhar a exception, seja em Message ou seja em InnerException para verificar qual foi o erro original.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, meu banco estava um varchar(16). Obrigado pela solução e ajuda.